# How to use autocomplete plugin for refresh a div?

Tags: html, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a doubt which involves an auto in a DIV (in which contains the name of other users with their image and age) when a user type the letters in a field that is positioned above the DIV.

As the auto search of Facebook friends.

Searching, I found a jQuery plugin that is the 'Autocomplete' but I want to modify to have the same behavior as facebook friend finder.

Does anyone have any example to do this? Or another way?

Note: I have a function in PHP that returns me all the names by letter. ¿I can consistently with ajax call this function to update the DIV?

Comment: [jQuery UI Documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) shows how to customize the display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery UI has some nice built in functionality for that

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

You can either go the javascript way when retrieving the suggestions or you could do the ajax calls - that depends mostly on how many entries you have that are possible matches.

If you have too many, storing all elements in js might not be the best way to go.

Comment: If i have a lot of elements.. what is the best way to go?

Comment: Check the 2nd example of the jQuery UI autocomplete demo gallery. It uses a remote database access script. This is what you should do. Set up a server sided script (e.g. in php) that returns suggestions depending on your input (e.g. adjust your mysql query) in JSON. Just follow the example on the jQuery UI site. Should be fairly easy to set up.